# Api for waveTable synthesis on android

Tags: java, android, audio, javasound

Could anyone tell me, Where can i find api for waveTable syntesis on android?

Or maybe i can use one of C++ waveTable synth libraries on android through JNI?

MediaPlayer and JetPlayer does not fit for this task.
I need to play MIDI, but with good soundbanks and be able to change soundbanks on user request.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR there's no API for this in SDK. If you want to play midi on android use MediaPlayer to do the playback (it does support midi files)

Comment: thanks you for answer, but i want play midi file with good soundbanks.

Comment: JetPlayer does not fit for this task.